# EOF во время ввода: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Мне необходимо, чтобы при вводе пользователем 1 и более чисел печатало кортеж из всех этих чисел. Вот так это сделал я:

```
print(eval("(" + input("Enter 2 numbers: ") + ")"))
```

И вот какую ошибку выдает интерпретатор при вводе чисел 2 и 16:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\Python Projects\USE_TEST_1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(eval("(" + input("Enter 2 numbers: ") + ")"))
  File "<string>", line 1
    2 16
       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Капитан Очевидность отмечает, что `(2 16)` на самом деле не является корректной синтаксической конструкцией в Python.

Comment: А ещё вы, похоже, запускаете это не в третьем питоне, а во втором, определитесь

Comment: `x = tuple(raw_input('prompt >> ').split())`

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение об ошибке не показывает у вас скобки `()`, поэтому ошибка в `input()` функции. Можно убедиться в этом, если в отдельной строке вызвать `input()`.

То что вы получили `SyntaxError`, вызывая `input()` функцию, указывает что вы запускаете код, используя Питон 2, а не Питон 3, не смотря на то что указано в метках вопроса. В Питоне 2, `input()` сам по себе работает по аналогии с `eval(raw_input())`.

`SyntaxError` вы получаете потому что, чтобы создать кортеж из двух чисел, необходимо *запятую* указать. При этом скобки совсем не нужны, если вы не хотите создать пустой кортеж: `()`.

Вот минимальное изменение к вашему коду в вопросе, чтобы он «печатал кортеж из всех этих чисел» (но прежде чем использовать пример, читайте ниже **"eval()—зло"** раздел):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
print input("Enter 2 comma-separated numbers: ")
```

или

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print(eval(input("Enter 2 comma-separated numbers: ")))
```

Если ввести:

```
2,16
```

то в ответ оба примера напечатают:

```
(2, 16)
```

## eval() — зло

Конечно, пользователь программы свободен указать [`__import__('os').remove('важный файл')`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zADUIwNwglM&feature=youtu.be&t=1m38s) вместо чисел. Поэтому более безопасный способ: прочесть строку и распознать заданный формат ввода вручную, например:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
print tuple(map(int, raw_input("Enter 2 comma-separated numbers: ").split(',')))
```

Или

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print(tuple(map(int, input("Enter 2 comma-separated numbers: ").split(','))))
```

Результаты те же, что и для предыдущих примеров.

Принимая ввод с клавиатуры, следует ожидать ошибок ввода, поэтому хорошо ловить исключения и повторить попытку получить числа, напечатав информативное сообщение об ошибке. См. [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279).